# File Expection Error

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been having problems with my code, I have created a Untitled file called seats.txt in the same src folder im using and it is bringing up an error saying that it cannot find the file.

```
package CW1;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;


public class CW1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileReader("seats.txt"));    

System.out.println("Do you have a Custom Discount Rate? (Yes or No)");  
 String discountRate = input.next();

 if (discountRate.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
    System.out.print("Please Enter a Custom Discount Rate");
    double discountRateY = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Custom rate of " + discountRateY + "% has been added");
 }
else if (discountRate.equalsIgnoreCase("No")){
    System.out.println("Default discount of 20.0% has been added");

}
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid ");

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the **working directory** is the project folder, not the `src` or `bin` folder.

- You can **modify your code** (see [Marcus Pitz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47164501/6505250)),
- move the file **`seats.txt` into the project folder** or
- **change the working directory** in the run configuration:

  1. *Run > Run Configurations...*
  2. In the tab *Arguments* choose as *Working directory* *Other*, click *Workspace...* and choose the folder that contains `seats.txt`
  3. Click *Run*

Answer (score 1):

The current directory depends where you run the application/class (it's a relative path). If you are in Eclipse, the directory is the working directory (out of src folder). If you are running the class, the directory is the same directory of the class.

On Eclipse use `Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileReader("src/seats.txt"));`